# How does Apple appstore handle versions?

Tags: app-store

What happens if I post a version for IOS 7 on the appstore and someone with IOS 6 attemps to get it? do they get a message? do they just fail?
Of course I cannot try this as Apple will delete my previous version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking of iOS 7 only applications the user will not be able to download the application until they have the correct OS running on their device. I believe if the application has a pre-iOS 7 version available it is possible to download this on earlier OS versions looking at the following documentation:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5919

also:

http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/17/apple-ios-last-compatible-version-app-iphone-ipod-ipad/